# Google Analytics Multi Channel Funnel API access to Custom Channel Groupings

Tags: google-analytics-api

You can get data from the Multi Channel Funnel (MCF) api segmented by the MCF Channel Grouping using the dimension mcf:basicChannelGrouping.

Is there any way to get attribution data segmented by a Custom Channel Grouping that a user has defined in their GA account?

If this is not possible in the MCF API, is it possible in any other Google Analytics API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on several searches, it seems Custom Channel Groupings are indeed **NOT** available in the MCF API, as of march 2017.